# Form matrix from rows in 3-dimensional array

Tags: r

I have `X`, a three-dimensional array in R. I want to take a vector of indices `indx` (length equal to `dim(X)[1]`) and form a matrix where the first row is the first row of `X[ , , indx[1]]`, the second row is the second row of `X[ , , indx[2]]`, and so on.

For example, I have:

```
R> X <- array(1:18, dim = c(3, 2, 3))
R> X
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7   10
[2,]    8   11
[3,]    9   12

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   13   16
[2,]   14   17
[3,]   15   18

R> indx <- c(2, 3, 1)
```

My desired output is

```
R> rbind(X[1, , 2], X[2, , 3], X[3, , 1])
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7   10
[2,]   14   17
[3,]    3    6
```

As of now I'm using the inelegant (and slow) `sapply(1:dim(X)[2], function(x) X[cbind(1:3, x, indx)])`.  Is there any way to do this using the built-in indexing functions?  I had no luck experimenting with the matrix indexing methods described in `?Extract`, but I may just be doing it wrong.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3551955/210673

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
t(sapply(1:3,function(x) X[,,idx][x,,x]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be answering the wrong question (I can't reconcile your first description and your sample output)... This produces your sample output, but I can't say that it's much faster without running it on your data.

`do.call(rbind, lapply(1:dim(X)[1], function(i) X[i, , indx[i]]))`

Answer (score 1):

Matrix indexing to the rescue! No `apply`s needed.

Figure out which indices you want:

```
n <- dim(X)[2]
foo <- cbind(rep(seq_along(indx),n),
             rep(seq.int(n), each=length(indx)),
             rep(indx,n))
```

(the result is this)

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    2
[2,]    2    1    3
[3,]    3    1    1
[4,]    1    2    2
[5,]    2    2    3
[6,]    3    2    1
```

and use it as index, converting back to a matrix to make it look like your output.

```
> matrix(X[foo],ncol=n)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7   10
[2,]   14   17
[3,]    3    6
```